# angular 8 - Filter an Array of objects by number

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, angular8

Is it possible to filter this list where iseidaCcaa.id is equal to a given number:

```js
var centers = [
  {
    id: 2,
    nombre: "Centro 2",
    iseidaCcaa: {
      id: 1,
    },
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    nombre: "Centro 3",
    iseidaCcaa: {
      id: 1,
    },
  },
  {
    id: 1,
    nombre: "Centro 1",
    iseidaCcaa: {
      id: 2,
    },
  },
];
```

I tried this  solution but it is not working

```
 this.centers = this.centers.filter(element => {
    return element.isiedaCcaa.id == 1;
  })
```

Comment: Looks like a typo: `isiedaCcaa` vs `iseidaCcaa`

Comment: @Phix. Beat me to it, was writing an answer. Lol. Definately a typo. @Oussama, though I wonder if you might wish to use `find()` instead of `filter()` to only return the first element that matches

Comment: Should check your typescript config too. I see you tagged the question as typescript, TS might have definitely caught that typo.

Comment: @iamcastelli, Sorry but I want to return all elements that match the number.

Comment: Ohh, then better use the filter.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You have a typo on the return.

should be `return element.iseidaCcaa.id == 1`

Although I would consider using === if the id is going to be int

Answer (score 1):

You wrong property by type iseidaCcaa not isiedaCcaa

```js
var centers = [    {
       "id":2,
       "nombre":"Centro 2",
       "iseidaCcaa":{
          "id":1,
       }

    },
    {
       "id":3,
   "nombre":"Centro 3",
   "iseidaCcaa":{
     "id":1,
   }
},
{
   "id":1,
   "nombre":"Centro 1",
   "iseidaCcaa":{
     "id":2,
   }
}
]

 var centers = centers.filter(element => {
    return element.iseidaCcaa.id == 1;
  })
  
  console.log(centers);
```